# facebook-c#-sdk

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I would like to host more applications on the same domain so to have, as canvas URL, subfolders like www.mydomain.com/app1, www.mydomain.com/app2 and so on.

I can't create singular virtual directories since just the root is an IIS virtual directory. So I was thinking to have in each VD just a file to redirect to a page on the root which can work as real entrypoint of the application (i.e. app1_default.aspx, app2_defaul.aspx etc.)

However, it looks as if it doesn't work because the "FacebookConfigurationSection" retrieves both the app ID and the Secret Key from the web.config, which is obviously unique.

Is there any workaround?

thanks

marco

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could accomplish this by having multiple config files within the application.  **[Here is the documentation for the scope of and protocols for having multiple config files in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx)**